# Include an EmberJS app inside given HTML tag

Tags: ember.js

**HTML**

header

```
`<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">  
    {{view App.NavbarView}}  
    {{outlet}}  
</script>`
```

footer

**JS**

```
`App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend();  
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({  
  templateName: 'application'  
});`  

App.Router = Em.Router.extend({
enableLogging: true,
location: 'hash',

root: Em.Route.extend({
  // EVENTS
  gotoAbout: Ember.Route.transitionTo('about'),

  // STATES
  about: Em.Route.extend({
    route: '/',
    connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
      router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('about');
    }
  })
```

I want remove `data-template-name="application"` because i want show this immediately in the place where is this block of code (between header and footer).

But when i remove this and `templateName: 'application'` router dont work.

**The question is:** How to show block

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">  
  {{view App.NavbarView}}  
  {{outlet}}  
</script>
```

between header and footer.

I know I can write `<div id="content"></div>` and use `.appendTo("content")` but maybe exist more optimal way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried to set App's `rootElement` property?

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#app-container'
});
```

You've got an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/FMV8u/2/), which you can easily derivate.

Comment: Thx. Its work. Any other way to do this? I want just get more knowledge about emberjs.

Comment: Well, it's the nominal way to do. You can plug an ember app anywhere inside a page, using this property.